# Make the sum of the hours participated in the date range

Tags: mysql, sum, where-clause

With several aids I was able to make this selection, but I need to add the hours and not repeat the students and show zero results when the student has not participated in that range of dates:

```
**students TABLE**

s_id
s_laname
s_mname
s_fname
s_grupo

**horas TABLE**

id
s_id
horas
fecha
grupo


SELECT students.s_lname, horas.horas 
FROM students 
LEFT JOIN horas ON students.s_id=horas.s_id 
       and horas.fecha >= '2020-11-01' 
       AND horas.fecha <= '2020-11-30' 
       AND horas.horas >'0' 
WHERE students.s_grupo IN('11')
```

this is the result with the select that I have posted, but I need it to do the sum of the hours:

```
s_lname   horas 
Molina      12  
Mejías      12  
Corrales    10  
Sáenz       15  
Castro      11  
Hernandez   11  
Sáenz       12  
Hernandez   6   
Hernandez   6   
Sáenz       12  
Brizuela    NULL
Vargas      NULL
Acuña       NULL
Jiménez     NULL
López.      NULL
Jimenez     NULL
Vargas      NULL
Navarro     NULL
```

This would be what I need, the students with the sum of the hours and who has not participated to put a NULL or a Zero:

```
s_lname   horas 
Molina      12  
Mejías      12  
Corrales    10  
Sáenz       39  
Castro      11  
Hernandez   33
Brizuela    NULL
Vargas      NULL
Acuña       NULL
Jiménez     NULL
López       NULL
Jimenez     NULL
Vargas      NULL
Navarro     NULL
```

Comment: Please put the code in a code box like ```This is code``` And also please send screenshots not pictures..... :(

Comment: Sorry I am new users and don't know how. little by little I am learning

Comment: I have edited my answer, see if it works now...

Comment: Hi @Yunfei Chen,
Thanks, with your help I have edited the select and now work fine. I am very happy.

SELECT students.s_lname, SUM(horas.horas)
    FROM students 
    LEFT JOIN horas ON students.s_id=horas.s_id 
           and horas.fecha >= '2020-11-01' 
           AND horas.fecha <= '2020-11-30' 
           AND horas.horas >'0' 
    WHERE students.s_grupo IN('11')
    Group by students.s_id

Comment: If it works now please accept the answer so others can refer to it...

Comment: Thanks @Yunfei Chen, I really appreciate your help, I am new to SOF but little by little I learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you can add a distinct keyword and use inner join instead of left join:

EDIT: Based on your result and the one you want I am guessing your wanna sum up the results, if that is true than....

```
SELECT students.s_lname, SUM(horas.horas)
    FROM students 
    LEFT JOIN horas ON students.s_id=horas.s_id 
           and horas.fecha >= '2020-11-01' 
           AND horas.fecha <= '2020-11-30' 
           AND horas.horas >'0' 
    WHERE students.s_grupo IN('11')
    Group by students.s_id
```

Comment: the results do not change. I need to SUM the hours and show all students in the student table, and show NULL or Zero if there is no record in the hours table for those who did not participate in the course

Comment: Wait you want to show null or zero if there are no records?? I thought you wanted to get rid of the null and zero records?? You are confusing me..... it says show zero results??

Comment: Also some records you got, different hours for the same person, which one are you trying to take, its confusing....

Comment: Right, I did not explain myself well. I have two tables, one students and one hours, the hours table records the hours they have taken, with date, course_id (grupo), student_id (s_id), I need to check by date range, how many hours the course (example grupo 11)  students have participated and what they have not done hours to put a zero.
The statement that I have posted works for me, it puts NULL in the students who do not have records in that range of dates, but it does not add the hours of the students, it shows me all the records of those students

Comment: @COINFEUROPEA I cant actually see the date, so that's gonna be a problem with your filter condition??

Comment: I do not understand what you say, the dates (for this example) are 2020-11-01 and 2020-11-30
(The hours table have the date field -- fecha)

Comment: @COINFEUROPEA I need a screenshot of your actual data..... the two tables before joining.....

Comment: I have edited the ask today, thanks for your help